# Expectation over Markov Process and discrete Ito integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus

I am doing a research on communication protocol design. 
A file of $n$ blocks is transferred in several rounds and
$R_i$ denotes the number of blocks received in the $i$-th round.
The sender sends $n-R_1-R_2-\cdots-R_{i-1}$ blocks in the $i$-th round and
$X_i$ denotes the state of the channel in the $i$-th round.
Actually, I would like to know the expected value of $\sum_{m=0}^l R_m$ to estimate the transmission rounds.

Assume that $X_i$ satisfies a first-order discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain with two states, thus I can obtain the random variables $R_i\mid R_1,R_2, \ldots, R_{i-1}, X_i$ conditioned on the previous states and the state of the $i$-th step of the Markov process $X$, i.e.,
$$
R_i \sim Bin(n-R_1-R_2-\cdots-R_{i-1},p(X_i)).
$$
By induction on $i$, we have $R_1+R_2+\cdots+R_i \mid X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_i$, i.e.,
$$
R_1+R_2+\cdots+R_i \sim Bin(n,1-\prod_{m=1}^{i} (1-p(X_i))).
$$
I would like to evaluate the expected value of $\sum_{m=1}^l R_m$, and deduce as follows.
$$
\begin{aligned}
  & \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{m=1}^l R_m \right] \\
= & \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{m=1}^l R_m \Bigg|  X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_l \right] \right]\\
= & \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\text{over } X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_l} \left[ n\times (1-\prod_{m=1}^{l} (1-p(X_m))) \right]\\
= & n \times \left( 1- \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\text{over } X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_l} \left[  \prod_{m=1}^{l}1-p(X_m) \right] \right).
\end{aligned}
$$
I stuck here because if I carry out the evaluation of the expectations, the number of terms would be $2^l$, which is too large for computation.

An alternative approach is to evaluate the random variable $\sum_{m=1}^l R_m$ using discrete Ito integral, hoping this will simply the formula of the expectation. But I lack the knowledge of real analysis and measure theory, self studying stochastic calculus is difficult for me.

Any suggestions or hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use $X_{i-1}$ instead?

Comment: I updated my question. @BCLC

Comment: Is l random? I think we can swap expectation and sum if the sum is finite

Comment: $l$ is not random. I don't swap expectation and sum because I already have the distribution of $\sum_{m=1}^l R_m$, which can be seen from the question. @BCLC

Comment: Use Markov property?

Comment: How to apply Markov property? @BCLC